# Resources in maven web application

Tags: maven

I have an web application which use maven as the build tool, this is the structure:

```
simple-app(war)
    src
        main
            java
                ...
            resources
                app.properties
            webapp
                ....
    target
        myapp
            WEB-INF
                classes
                    app.properties
                    #classes
```

Now I want to make the classes as a jar, and put it to the WEB-INF/lib.

So I tried to splite the project to

```
simple-server(jar)
    src/main
        java
            ....
        resources
            ....
simple-web(war)
        webapp
```

Not the resources are attached to the simple-server.jar, which is not expected, since I want the resources(*.properties) be inside the WEB-INF/classes.

It seems that I have to put the resources(*.properties) in the `simple-web` project, however the `simple-web` and `simple-server` should be maintained by two team, and the resources is bound to the `simple-server` module, it should be put inside the `simple-server` module.

Is this possible?